# 3D Interpolation, which would be the best solution to interpolate?

Tags: math, 3d, interpolation

I want to get the point "Search".

All other points are known.

A, B, C, D are always Z=0

F, E, G, H 's Z could be anything above 0 (Z-Axis is representing a surface)

"I" is also known (X, Y, Z=0)

"Search" = (I.X, I.Y and Z =?)
So I need something to calculate "Search.Z"

I guess there is already something like this in 3D libraries.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, the choice of interpolation method depends on whether your data fall on a regular grid or not.

If you have a regular grid then you should use recursive interpolation. From your 8 points you would do 4 interpolations, say along the y axis. From the resulting rectangle you would do 2 interpolations, say along the x axis. Then you would do an interpolation along the z axis. If you just have the 8 points you describe then you can only realistically perform linear interpolation (unless you have some other constraints like known values of the slope at the edges). If you have more points [at least 4 for each desired dimension] then you can use cubic interpolation.

If you have an irregular grid then there are several [techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation#Irregular_grid_.28scattered_data.29).